# Where do suggested edits go?

Tags: discussion, editing

What kind of queue do suggested edits go into? Is this part of the moderator tools or is there some other way view these?

Having recently earned the ability to edit rather than just suggest, I was curious if there is a way to contribute by checking and approving edits or if that has to be done by moderators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're 10K+ you'll see a counter notification in the top menu. Jeff covered this in a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) -- See item #2.  Else, you'll just have to "luck out" and browse to a post containing awaiting edits.

<s>There is probably something in the MSO FAQ, but I haven't had enough coffee to dig for it.</s>

Following half-a-cup, here is a mildly related [MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work). It is still marked [faq-proposed], so please take with the appropriate grain(s) of salt.

Comment: @Chris "Page Not Found" for bottom-feeders like me.  I think that's the *super seekret 10K page* :)

Comment: This answer seems outdated. These days that review queue is available to anyone with 2K reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that there would not be an interface for doing something that you actually have permissions to do, but I found there is a backdoor into this function.

If you look at the revision history to any edit that was initiated by a suggestion, there is a link to the suggestion review page. The edits are filed with an incremental counter, so if you manually increment the number in the URL you can scroll through the suggested edit queue. When you find the top, if there are unapproved edits you (with 2k+ rep) will actually be able to approve them even though only the 10k rep guys get shown the queue.

Comment: Have a look at the discussion in the comments to [this question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1288/can-the-links-to-useful-chat-rooms-be-made-permanent) and specifically at the link that Balpha provided for me. It's one of the SE culture things that is heavily weighted by SO. It appears to be relatively easy to gain rep on SO so people come into their powers before fully understanding the culture so things are hidden from them and consequently everyone else.

Comment: Thanks @lain. I see the rational, although the sites I am most active on work at a little bit different pace.